# Range query in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

Hi guys im trying to do a range query in jpa where i can search a DOB between a set range

i get the user to enter the details on a calander and then pass it to this code

```
public List<User> dobRangeSearch(Date dateOfBirthSearch1, Date dateOfBirthSearch2) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM USERS U WHERE u.DATEOFBIRTH BETWEEN "+  dateOfBirthSearch1 + " and " + dateOfBirthSearch2);
    return q.getResultList();

}
```

but i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM USERS U WHERE u.DATEOFBIRTH BETWEEN Sun Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2013 and Wed Dec 04 00:00:00 GMT 2013]. 
[28, 95] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
```

what is the correct way to run this search ?

thanks

EDIT

even though i had created the values using the calander and date functions the records that get put into the database is in the format

```
'2013-12-02'
```

so how can i strip the data from the input to just this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You putting the `Date.toString()` output inside your query so either use a DateFormater to get your Date String in the right format your use parameters.

```
public List<User> dobRangeSearch(Date dateOfBirthSearch1, Date dateOfBirthSearch2) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM USERS U WHERE u.DATEOFBIRTH BETWEEN :date1 and :date2)
      .setParameter("date1", dateOfBirthSearch1)
      .setParameter("date2", dateOfBirthSearch2;
    return q.getResultList();

}
```

Comment: I recommend specifying TemporalType as well.